Securely connect from Power Automate (Cloud) to private endpoint in Azure
Let us say I am using Power Automate, and I have a "cloud flow". What is the canonical way to connect to a private end point in an Azure VNet?
Is there a way of creating a VPN connection back from Azure using a VPN Gateway and a Local Network Gateway? This would be the case for an on-premises network, and there is an abundance of documentation for this. But how to do it for Power Automate?
Let us say it is to query a SQLServer. No public network access. I stress the connection is not from on-premises but from the Power Automate cloud.
Yes I am aware they are in the same data centre, and yes I am aware that the PaaS uses Azure as the back end. How can I reach the private endpoint without the use of public outbound IP addresses?

Even a solution where Power Automate uses ExpressRoute to On-Premises where the On-Premises is actually the Azure VNet.

Actually Azure blob doesn't support connection to private endpoints even through gateway. Please refer to this documention by MSFT: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/azureblob/  (refer point 5,6 and 8)

@Sumit Singh Noted, updating the question to SQLSerrver.

I am not sure if this will help, but what I did (using service ID), gave it access to the database (SQL Server) and then enable the SQLServer in the On-Prem data gateway. Once the option is enabled and Gateway is shared with the service setup is done. Then I created the connection reference (for deployment), I used that gateway and SQL credentials to connect.
